# How to keep watchdog monitoring after shell disconnect?

Tags: python, scripting, watchdog

I have a watchdog observer running to monitor new files in a folder.  Everything runs fine until i disconnect my client from the shell.  When I reconnect it isnt monitoring anymore.

Is there a way to keep the monitor even if client disconnect?

I run my script with:

```
python watchscript.py /path/to/folder/to/monitor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nohup` is a command that will run another command, and make it immune to the "hangup" signal.

You run it as simply as:

```
nohup command
```

but you will also need to redirect stdin, stdout and stderr. See the man page for more info.

You'll also probably want to put it in the background.

```
nohup command &
```

You will also need to know the kill command to eventually kill it.